# VS2010 Class Diagram - How to show collection associations between two interfaces?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, generics, uml, class-diagram

I'm generating some class diagrams from existing code to improve the documentation but I've run into a bit of an obstacle. I'd like to show collection associations on the diagram, but for interfaces this just doesn't seem possible.

If the interfaces are in another assembly, the collection type is displayed in its unbounded form (e.g. `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`1`) and attempting to display collection associations gives the error

> This is not a valid type name.

If the interfaces are in the same assembly, the collection type is displayed in its bounded form (e.g. ReadOnlyObservableCollection`), but attempts to display the associations come out with the error message

> Cannot show an association because  cannot be found.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, or is this just a shortcoming of VS class diagrams?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 4):

I found that by removing and removing and re-adding the reference of the assemble containing the offending class, solved the issue.